# jq: how to check two conditions in the any filter?

Tags: unix, jq

I have this line `jq 'map(select( any(.topics[]; . == "stackoverflow" )))'`

Now I want to modify it (I didn't write the original) to add another condition to the any function.

Something like this `jq 'map(select( any(.topics[]; . == "stackoverflow" and .archived == "false" )))'`

But it gives me “Cannot index string with string “archived”".

The archive field is on the same level as the topics array (it's repo information from the github API).

It is part of a longer command, FYI:

```
repositoryNames=$(curl \
      -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
      "https://api.github.com/orgs/organization/repos?per_page=100&page=$i" | \
    jq 'map(select(any(.topics[]; . == "stackoverflow")))' | \
    jq -r '.[].name')
```

Comment: what is the format of your input?

Comment: @OznOg Check again! I added the full command if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator provided to `any` already descends to `.topics[]` from where you cannot back-reference two levels higher. Use the `select` statement to filter beforehand (also note that booleans are not strings):

```bash
jq 'map(select(.archived == false and any(.topics[]; . == "stackoverflow")))'
```

---

You should also be able to combine both calls to `jq` into one:

```bash
jq -r '.[] | select(.archived == false and any(.topics[]; . == "stackoverflow")).name'
```

Comment: That worked (I tried your first suggestion)! Many thanks. And 'doh at the boolean not being a string, of course, how stupid of me. :D